# Get raw HEX from HEX string

Tags: javascript, escaping, hex, character, ascii

I've spend the last few hours researching, but couldn't find anything suiting my needs.

I need to send escaped hex values to a device via TCP, like this:

```
var char = "\x14";
```

Now i need to get the size of a string and convert it in escaped hex, like the above, dynamically.

Converting from decimal is easy of course:

```
var string = "qwertzuiopasdfghjkly"; //Length 20
var hex = (string.length).toString(16); //Returns 14
```

I've tried it via non-displayable ASCII characters:

```
char = String.fromCharCode(hex);
```

But that doesn't return the same as

```
char = "\x14";
```

Already found the solution in other languages, but not JavaScript ...

Comment: e.g. in Python `chr(len(string))` would do it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, i was looking for `String.fromCodePoint()`, a relatively new function, specified in ECMAScript 2015.
I also had to use utf8 Encoding to make it work.

```
var string = "qwertzuiopasdfghjkly"; //Length 20
var char = String.fromCodePoint(string.length) // Equivalent to char = "\x14";
```

More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint